# How to reverse CSS animation when using both width and max-width

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'd like to reverse a CSS animation where a combination of "width" and "max-width" is being used.

Currently, the animation shown in this fiddle expands properly when "Toggle" is clicked, but it just "snaps" back to the original width then the toggle button is clicked again.

How do I make it return smoothly to the original state?

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/opradf20/

```js
const toggle = () => {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('grow');
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 40vw;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
.sidebar.grow {
    transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: max-width 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar.grow {
    width: 90vw;
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle Growth</button>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the transition property in the sidebar class.
2. set the transition property only once (separate the orders with comma). Otherwise the second order will override the first order.

```js
const toggle = () => {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('grow');
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 40vw;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  transition: width 500ms ease-in-out, max-width 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar.grow {
    width: 90vw;
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle Growth</button>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
</html>
```